# Error on LINQ statement with enclosing variable

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Trying to run the following LINQ statment:

```
Dim jobId As Integer = CInt(payment.ForJob)

Dim currentPaid = From a In db.Payments
                      Where a.ForJob = jobId
                      Select a.Amount
```

Get the following error on a.Amount though:
Range variable 'Amount' hides a variable in an enclosing block or a range variable previously defined in the query expression

```
Function RecordPaymentForJob(payment As Payment) As ActionResult
        If ModelState.IsValid Then

            Dim jobId As Integer = CInt(payment.ForJob)

            Dim new currentPaid = From a In db.Payments
                      Where a.ForJob = jobId
                      Select a.Amount

            Dim totalPaid As Double = currentPaid.Sum()

            If (totalPaid + payment.Amount) > (db.Jobs.Find(payment.ForJob).JobAmount * -1) Then
                db.Jobs.Find(payment.ForJob).JobStatus = "Paid"
            Else
                db.Jobs.Find(payment.ForJob).JobStatus = "Part Paid"
            End If

            Dim Id As Integer = payment.CustomerId
            Dim amount As Double = db.Customers.Find(Id).AccBalance
            amount += payment.Amount
            db.Customers.Find(Id).AccBalance = amount
            db.Payments.Add(payment)
            db.SaveChanges()
            Return Redirect("/Payment/PaymentSuccessful")
        End If

        Return View(payment)
    End Function
```

Comment: Could you show a complete method demonstrating the problem? It feels like there's context missing here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this is the problem:

```
Dim amount As Double = db.Customers.Find(Id).AccBalance
```

I don't know VB very well, but I suspect the scope of this variable is the scope of the whole block, including that LINQ statement. In C# at least, that wouldn't be a problem... but the [`Select`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384607.aspx) clause in VB works somewhat differently, I believe.

One alternative would be to compute the sum directly:

```
Dim totalPaid = db.Payments.Where(Function(a) a.ForJob = jobId).
                            Sum(Function(a) a.Amount)
```

My VB is pretty poor, but I *think* that should work.

Comment: Works wonderfully and you answered a question I had asked elsewhere!